# How can I implement the excel's SMALL and LARGE functions in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

[LARGE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LARGE-function-3af0af19-1190-42bb-bb8b-01672ec00a64) lets you find the nth largest value in an array. [SMALL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SMALL-function-17da8222-7c82-42b2-961b-14c45384df07) lets you find the nth smallest value in an array.

I want to do something like `select SMALL([col1, col2, col3, 2], 2),  LARGE([col1, col2, col3, 5], 2) from table1;`

I am not looking for the [GREATEST and LEAST FUNCTIONS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST). I want to find the nth smallest/largest values and not *the* smallest/largest values.

Comment: Are those numbers or character values?

Comment: Numbers is what I will supply in args

Comment: If it's only integers, consider using the [intarray](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html) extension's `sort()` function instead of unnesting and aggregating in the function, e.g: `(sort(array[3,5,1,2]))[2]` that will be a lot faster.

Comment: The columns I plan to use are `Numeric`. Is there a NumericArray sort of thing? I look at the solution and worry about performance for large number of rows.

Comment: No, that extension is only for integers.

Comment: Got it. thanks for taking time out to help me out :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The implementation is very simple:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION large(anyarray, int)
 RETURNS anyelement AS $$
  SELECT (ARRAY(SELECT unnest($1) ORDER BY 1 DESC))[$2]
 $$ LANGUAGE sql;

postgres=# SELECT large(ARRAY[3,2,1,4,5,0], 2);
┌───────┐
│ large │
╞═══════╡
│     4 │
└───────┘
(1 row)
```

For a "small" function - remove `DESC` in `ORDER BY` clause.

The implementation is based on `unnest` function - it transforms a array to table. It is sorted by `ORDER BY` clause - like any other table. A array constructor `ARRAY(subselect)` transforms sorted relation to array.

This functions uses a polymorphic arguments - it is similar to templates in C++. With these parameters this function is working with any array type.

Comment: using a `variadic` parameter probably matches the original function better.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - why - there is not necessary variadic, because first argument is a array already.

Comment: But you can't call it like this then `large(col1, col2, col3, 1)` as show in the question.

Comment: I see in question some different `select SMALL([col1, col2, col3, 2], 2),` and when I look to ms doc, then this function is not variadic too.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I love your idea too. I am not so particular about one way or another. Thanks for the answer pavel-stehule!

Comment: Though the implementation in the answer is the small function and not the large function as it gives the nth smallest value.

Comment: @RanjithRamachandra - you have true, fixed.